# how to convert map to a list of collection, where map key and value are the fields of that collection?

Tags: scala

I have a class like

```
class BN {
val id: Long
val score: Option[Double]
}
```

And a `map: Map[Long, Option[Double]]` 
 I want to convert map into `List[BN]`, where `id` is the key and `score` is the value.

Is there any easier way to do it other than coding step by step like java?

Comment: `map.iterator.map(BN).toList`. But you should turn your class into a **case class** first - `final case class BN(id: Long, score: Option[Double])`.

Answer (score 2):

Class you declared above is abstract: it declares 2 `val` fields but does not provide an implementation, this code won't compile without `abstract` modifier. As @Luis mentioned in the comment, most likely you need to declare a [case class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html)

```
// this is a class with 2 args
class BN(val id: Int, val score: Option[Double])

// this is a case class, depends on the usecase it might be more convenient
case class CBN(val id: Int, val score: Option[Double])

// abstract class with abstract members
abstract class ABN{
  val id: Int
  val score: Option[Double] 
}

var data = Map(1->Option(1.0), 2-> Option(2.0))

// map to case class using its automatically generated apply() method
data.map(t=> CBN(t._1, t._2))
// map regular class using 'new' keyword
data.map(t=> new BN(t._1, t._2))
// create new implementation overriding fields, don't do this in your case
data.map(t=> new ABN{val id=t._1 ; val score=t._2 })
```

Answer (score 0):

For data structures you really should use `case classes`.

In addition to *Fenixil*'s answer, you could add a constructor in the companion object, to hide the *ugly* stuff for the caller.

Change to `case class`:

```
case class BN(id: Int, score: Option[Double])
```

No `val`s needed, as `case classes` are *immutable* by default.

Provide a constructor in the `companion object`:

```
object BN {
  def apply(entry: (Int, Option[Double])):BN = 
     BN(entry._1, entry._2)
}
```

Usage:

```
val data = Map(1->Option(1.0), 2-> Option(2.0))
data.map(BN.apply)
```

This gives you: `List(BN(1,Some(1)), BN(2,Some(2)))`